# Symfony - how to serve image from controller with nginx's X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: nginx, symfony

I want to serve protected images to authorized users only. So therefore I'm using `BinaryFileResponse` within controller and it works fine. However, I would like to use the Nginx's XSendfile (X-Accel-Redirect). I've done the same steps as explained in Nginx's [documantation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/).

Also I've added the `BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();` to controller. But now I'm keep getting a 404 response.

Here are my configs and code:

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name symfony.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/Sites/Symfony/web";

    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php app_dev.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /images/ {
        internal;
        alias   /home/vagrant/Sites/Symfony/app/media/images/listings/4/;
    }

    client_max_body_size 100m; 

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;  # allows trailing slash after app_dev.php/
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/symfony.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/symfony.app.key;
}
```

Symfony Controller:

```
public function getPictureAction($id)
    {
        $filePath = 'media/images/listings/4/';
        $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/' . $filePath . $id;

        BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
        return $response;
    }
```

So, going to **http://symfony.app/images/1.jpg** should return an image, but got a 404.

Comment: add to OP the url that you use to get photo through `getPictureAction`

Comment: @MaxP. Hi. I don't get what you mean by OP?

Comment: OP = original post, question

Comment: @MaxP. Read my post carefully, the url is at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/images/` location is marked as internal, so it is not accessible for external requests from browser.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal

I think that route path for `getPictureAction` is `/images/{id}`, and it is not accessible because nginx has same location `/images/` that is internal and returns 404 error.

Rename nginx location to `/images-internal/`:

```
location /images-internal/ {
    internal;
    alias   /home/vagrant/Sites/Symfony/app/media/images/listings/4/;
}
```

And change php code to:

```
public function getPictureAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/' . 'media/images/listings/4/';
    $path = $dir . $id;

    $request->headers->set('X-Sendfile-Type', 'X-Accel-Redirect');
    $request->headers->set('X-Accel-Mapping', $dir . '=/images-internal/');

    BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();

    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: It worked. It was hard to see if an image has directly been served by nginx (can't find anything in headers), but by debugging the BinaryFileResponse class I could actually see that your solution really works. Thank you!

Comment: why isn't this part of the symfony documentation?